# Tire flat after 2nd trip on Brand New Ancheer 500W Ebike

Tags: mountain-bike, tire-pressure

Ok, so I am new to biking and don't know squat, as you will soon see. I bought a brand new E-bike, an Ancheer 500W. I borrowed an air pump, but had no pressure gauge when I first aired up the tires... they felt firm when I pressed them, but when I sat on the bike, I could see the tires going down.

So I ordered a new air pump with a pressure gauge, and when I checked the tires they only registered about 17lbs. each. The recommended pressure on the tire sidewall is 40/65 PSI, but when I got to 35lbs the tires were rock solid and I was afraid they would burst If I kept going (I'm probably an idiot).

I took it for a ride, and it the ride was great, screaming down the road. I came home, put it away... then a few hours later I check it and the rear tire is completely flat! I checked for nails or screws but found nothing. So I aired it up again, to 35 lbs. and then listened for a leak. I heard nothing. It seems like its perfectly fine again.

After all that my question is this: Would the fact that I only went to 35lbs of pressure be the reason it went flat after my ride? If so, I don't get it, because my first ride was half that pressure and it never went flat.

Also, if the tire feels rock solid when I touch it at 35 lbs. is it still safe to keep putting air up to the middle of that recommended range? Is it possible it could pop right in my face?

Comment: There's a lot to be said for having someone show you in person how to change a tube, and patch a puncture.   Its not hard, but there's a lot of technique to it.   Is there a local cyclist you can ask for a demo ?

Answer (score 8):

Based on this... [https://www.amazon.com/ANCHEER-Electric-Commuter-Removable-Professional/dp/B0BFQZHVZH?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BFQZHVZH)

The correct tire pressure for riding on the road is probably somewhere around 30-40PSI. Too low (like 17PSI) and you are vulnerable to pinch flats (When you hit a bump, the tube is pinched and punctures).  Too high, and the ride is harsh and uncomfortable.  There is no single "correct" tire pressure. It depends on your weight and riding style, and the balance of comfort and performance.

As far as the tire being flat, if the leak is large enough to hear it, the tire will be flat in minutes.  In this case, one of two things happened - the leak was in the valve, and has cleared with reinflating the tire, or there is a puncture and for some reason it is sealed up, possibly temporarily.

Hard to know what to advise - personally I would whip the tube out, inflate it and test for leaks in a bucket of water. You may decide to risk it and ride the bike - in that case, carry a tube and pump with you, and learn how to replace the tube if you do get a puncture (This is something every rider should do all the time, punctures happen).

Comment: Thanks for the response...being 320 lbs.... I was thinking I need to ride near the top of the 65PSI.... Currently I have 35 in the front and feels rock solid to touch... so maybe ill ride a few times at that pressure....and see how it rides.